# onFocus doesn't trigger showing and hide list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Any clue what's wrong in my code? my onFocus event doesn't work on a `div`

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  state = {
    openDropdown: false
  }
  toggleDropdown = () => {
  alert('x')
    this.setState({
        openDropdown: !this.state.openDropdown
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onFocus={this.toggleDropdown} onBlur={this.toggleDropdown}>
          MyList
        </div>
        <ul className={this.state.openDropdown ? 'show' : 'hide'}>
          <li>abc</li>
          <li>123</li>
          <li>xyz</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sua5j29b/

There's another problem in this approach, how can I close the dropdown when I click on one of the list? If I change the state of openDropdown, the behavior can be ruined.

Answer (score 1):

To apply onFocus or onBlur on a div I have to use

`tabIndex='0'` on the `div`